# HttpURLConnection DELETE with url params

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, http-delete

How to send url params with HttpURLConnection DELETE method?

I am using below code:

```
String targetURL = "http://example.com/some:data?initiator_id=6724181421";
URL url = new URL(targetURL);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty ("dev_key", "12345");
connection.setReadTimeout(60000);
connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
connection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
    }
    rd.close();
}
```

When I am executing the above code I am always getting the response as invalid initiator_id. I have tested the same with Postman and curl. In both curl and Postman it is working.

Comment: Are you trying to set `initiator_id` as a query parameter (part of the url) or as a form parameter (embedded in the body of the request)?

Comment: trying to add as query params (part of the url). When I am trying to add as form parameter I am getting exception "HTTP method DELETE doesn't support output"

Comment: I was sending form parameter as DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream ());
                    wr.writeBytes ("initiator_id=6724181421");
                    wr.flush ();
                    wr.close ();       But getting exception "HTTP method DELETE doesn't support output"

Comment: [That bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7157360) that was fixed in Java 1.8. Are you able to upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @dnault. Updating to Java 1.8 and sending initiator_id as form parameter fixed the issue.